# HTPP Error 403 while pulling JSON feed when I definitely have access

Tags: python, arrays, json, http-status-code-403, gspread

Confused as to why I'm seeing the 403 Forbidden error when I have access.  I tested out the API, I can print to terminal no problem with this script:

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# import urllib3
# import certifi
# # urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

# http = urllib3.PoolManager(
#     cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
#     ca_certs=certifi.where())


url = 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random'

req = rq.get(url, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')


print(soup)
```

But when I try to print to my Google sheet with the script below, I run into an issue:

```
# import urllib library
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

import gspread


gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1-1aiGMn2yUWRlh_jnIebcMNs-6phzUNxkktAFH7uY9o')
worksheet = sh.sheet1


url = 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random'


# store the response of URL
response = urlopen(url)

# storing the JSON response
# from url in data
data_json = json.loads(response.read())

# print the json response
# print(data_json)
result = []
for key in data_json:
    result.append([key, data_json[key] if not isinstance(
        data_json[key], list) else ",".join(map(str, data_json[key]))])
worksheet.update('a1', result)
```

I tested out the G Sheet, and pushed data there no problem.  The issue is coming from the JSON feed, not the connection through Gspread.

Any thoughts on how I could get this going directly into my google sheet?

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\Users\AMadle\NBA-JSON-Fetch\PrintToSheetTest.py", line 17, in <module>
    response = urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, I thought that when "User-Agent" is set, your issue might be able to be removed. So, in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
response = urlopen(url)
```

#### To:

```
response = urlopen(Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": ""}))
```

Or, please include a sample value of "User-Agent" as follows.

```
response = urlopen(Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": "###sample user agent###"}))
```

- In this case, please modify `from urllib.request import urlopen` to `from urllib.request import urlopen, Request`.

Comment: Phenomenal solution @Tainaike -- you are unreal.  I'm now dealing with a separate issue LOL with my script timing out (the active link is just a placeholder for the real one I need)... going to exhaust some options before coming here again though. Thank you!

Comment: @Anthony Madle Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.